# Como fazer meu projeto ASP.Net MVC enxergar pastas com imagens?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com uma dúvida, tenho uma pasta com imagens inclusa no meu projeto ASP.NET MVC, porém quando meu projeto está sendo executado ele não mapeia essa pasta assim não podendo incluir imagens ao meu site.

Tenho o seguinte caminho **`Content/NewTheme/img/`**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que após a execução do meu projeto não mapeia o diretório mostrado acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Ficar editando a pergunta com informação irrelevante só pra ela aparecer no topo do site não vai te ajudar em nada. Ao invés disso, se esforce em escrever melhor sua pergunta, tentar explicar o problema com mais clareza e (se for necessário) adicionar um [mcve].

Comment: Poste a parte onde você esta usando a imagem. O CÓDIGO.

Comment: Caso necessite de mais ajuda, poste o código que está usando para adicionar a imagem para eu possamos ver.

Comment: @SamuelAalmeida, qual é código e qual o erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem algo errado no seu código e não no "mapeamento".

Se você observar o caminho que ele está tentando buscar a imagem é:

```
http://localhost:1739/assets/img/user.png
```

Porém, no na sua imagem mostra claramente que o caminho é:

```
http://localhost:1739/Content/NewTheme/img/user.png
```

Altere o caminho para o diretório correto que a imagem aparecerá normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, pela dica que resolveu meu problema, um pequeno detalhe muito obrigado!!